# How to SELECT one day's scene (Landsat 8 scenes)

Tags: postgis, landsat-8

I have a huge dataset of raster in PostGIS. Each scene is divided into tiles (tile-size 500x500). I was trying to `SELECT rast FROM landsat8 WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, polygon)`. It runs very slow, because it returns longitudinal scenes of raster. Where I just want one day's scene.
 But the problem is if I query with fixed date, adjacent scene with different date won't be selected. That's not true.
So I think about some solutions:

- Because Landsat 8 re-visiting every 16 days, so I will insert every 16 days into different table. So I can query from raster that cover all the earth without duplicate.
- I'm not sure about ST_Within(), ST_DWithin() then SELECT rast that doesn't overlap other >50%

What would you do in this situation?